# Rails 3 Finding day of week

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

I'm trying to make my own calendar because i cant seem to get any help with event calendar so what im trying to do is Display the day of the week ie.. January 1 2011 is a Saturday is there an easy command to get that day or do i need something else

Answer (score 135, accepted):

Can't you use [time.wday](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core/classes/Time.html#M000369), 0 = sunday and so on

Comment: that works even better than Date::DAYNAMES[month] thanks for the help

Answer (score 163):

You can also get the string, like "Wednesday", using [time.strftime](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Time.html#method-i-strftime)("%A")

Comment: Best answer! Thank you

Answer (score 10):

Actively using in Rails 4 - should in most other versions as well...

Both of these options will give you the day string (eg. "Saturday") for the date specified:

**Specific date:**

```
Date.new(2011, 1, 1).strftime('%A') # returns "Saturday"
```

**Today:**

```
Date.today.strftime('%A')
```

Answer (score 4):

If you're attempting to write your own calendar from scratch and want to write a function to do day lookup, you might want to check out [Conway's Doomsday Algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Doomsday_rule), which is an interesting method for determining the day of the week on any given date. Otherwise the [standard time class](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core/classes/Time.html) has a wday method which returns a number from 0-6 (0 is Sunday, 1 is Monday, etc).

Comment: i found Date.today.beginning_of_month.wday works exactly the same way for what i was looking for but i will take a look at your link just to see if it might make my life easier.

Answer (score 4):

We can use Time.now.utc.wday to get day of week without considering zone.

Answer (score 1):

No need to use the `Time` class. `date.cwday` will return 1 for Monday, 2 for Tuesday etc.