# Where to put "conversions" for database content in Ruby on Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, helper

I store the day of the week as an integer from 0 to 6 in the database.
Now when I want to use that data in a view I want it to show as "Sunday", "Monday", etc.

Where should I put that kind of conversion? In a helper? Is there a best practice for this?

Comment: The normal approach for this kind of thing is to use localisation via `yaml` files in the config/locale directory. I'm no expert on this so I'll let someone else answer but this should give you something to investigate. Also, if it's only days of the week this question might help: http://stackoverflow.com/q/4844498/385532

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ruby has a [Date::DAYNAMES](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.0/libdoc/date/rdoc/Date.html) constant which contains an array of strings with the full name of days of the week in English, the first being "Sunday". Thus you could simply create a helper like so

```
def day_of_the_week(day)
  Date::DAYNAMES[day]
end
```

Usage

```
day_of_the_week(0) #=> "Sunday"
```

Comment: Thank you! In the end I used the localized version: `I18n.translate("date.day_names")[day]`