# How can I output the day of week with embedded ruby?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Right now I have the date displayed in the format mm/dd/yyyy by using `<h6><%= Time.now.strftime("%m/%d/%Y") %></h6>` but I want the day of week as well. Preferably it would display like: Wednesday, October 2. Thanks

Comment: possible duplicate of [Rails 3 Finding day of week](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4844498/rails-3-finding-day-of-week)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Say i have date = Time.now.to_date then date.strftime("%A") will print name for the day of the week and to have just the number for the day of the week write date.wday.

Copy from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13468235/1202324)

So `Time.now.strftime("%A")` and in your case

```
<h6>
  <%= Time.now.strftime("%A, %B %d. %Y") %>
</h6>
```

Easiest to test this is the `rails c`. To remove the leading zero on the `%d` use `%-d` instead.

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to get the full weekday name with %A (i.e. Sunday) and the abbreviated weekday name with %a (i.e. Sun).

Answer (score 1):

Using pure ruby class [***`Date`***](http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.0.0/libdoc/date/rdoc/Date.html) and [***`Time`***](http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.0.0/libdoc/date/rdoc/Time.html)

```
require 'time'
require 'date'

t = Time.now
t.wday # => 3
Date::ABBR_DAYNAMES[t.wday]
# => "Wed"
Date::DAYNAMES[t.wday]
# => "Wednesday"
```

Comment: Thought also about this, but since he is using RoR... Why not use the given functions.