# Validate Rails date not to allow Sundays

Tags: ruby-on-rails, validation

I need to keep a certain record from being created if the selected calendar date (not created_at) is on a Sunday.  I'm not sure how to do that.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Rails 3 Finding day of week](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4844498/rails-3-finding-day-of-week)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You'll need a custom validator for that. Add this to your model:

`validate :date_is_not_sunday`

Then the code for the validation:

```
def date_is_not_sunday
  if date_field.present? && date_field.wday == 0
    errors.add(:date_field, "Date can't be sunday")
  end
end
```

Edited to add Federico's recommendation

Answer (score 3):

I tried the answer provided by Juan Fuentes, and was getting a `NoMethodError` whenever the `date_field` was nil, as the `wday` method is not defined for the nil class.

What worked for me is to apply the `date_is_not_sunday` method only when `date_field` is present:

```
def date_is_not_sunday
  if date_field.present? && date_field.wday == 0
   errors.add(:date_field, "Date can't be sunday")
  end
end
```

Answer (score 1):

According to [kd7](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4844526) and [the documentation](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.3/Time.html#method-i-wday) you can set the date you want to check to the and then call t.wday and you can send an error if the.wday is 0 (Sunday).